# Understanding the fundamental theorem of finitely generated module over PID $\{x \in R/(p^k) : px=0 \} \cong R/(p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently taking an Abstract Algebra course and having hard time understanding the observation in the proof of the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules of PID (in particular, uniqueness).

In the notes, I have:

Observe that $$\{x \in R/(p^k) : px=0 \} \cong R/(p)$$
as an $R/(p)$-module

where $R$ is PID and $p$ prime.

This is not immediately clear.

Can someone elaborate on this? 
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see this is to note that if $px = 0$ in $R/(p^k)$ then $x$ is divisible by $p^{k-1}$, and try the obvious isomorphism $x \mapsto \frac{x}{p^{k-1}}$.